# JS: Show/hide text field depending on radio button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JS that shows a test field if "1" is selected from a radio button. And hides if "0" is selected. It's working while the text field is hidden from the beginning but not if I want the text field to be visible as default if the value is "1" from the database.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#send_to_yes").hide();
        $("input:radio[name=\'article\']").change(function() {  
                if(this.value == \'1\' && this.checked){
                    $("#send_to_yes").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#send_to_yes").hide();
                }
        });
});
```

**HTML**

```
Yes <input type="radio" name="article" value="1"> 
No <input type="radio" name="article" value="0">
<div id="send_to_yes">
       <b>Number</b> <br><input type="text" name="number"><br><br>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#send_to_yes {
        display: none;
}
```

The "1" and "0" comes from a database. With this code I need to press "Yes" and then the text field comes up. Even if "Yes" is checked I need to press it. I want it to be visible if "1" (Yes) is checked as default.

Comment: `if(this.value == \'1\'` Why are these quotes escaped?

Comment: Because I use echo '' (PHP) to display the JS. But it's working if not "Yes" is checked as default, so even if I use echo '' the code executes properly.

Comment: I don't see why you would do that. You'd be better off putting it in a `.js` file.

Comment: Do you think it will work then? I can try.

Comment: Also, I don't really understand the problem nor the question. Anyway, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5bJV/) of your question, it seems to work here.

Comment: It didn't worked with a .JS-file, or it works exactly as before. In you Fiddle none if the radio buttons is checked from the beginning. The value (1 or 0) is fetched for the database. If the value is 1 I want the text field to be displayed. And if the value is 0 I want it to hide the text field. Now I need to press Yes (even if Yes already is checked) to show the text field.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/5ErLu/1/)

Html

```
Yes <input type="radio" name="article" value="1" checked='checked'> 
No <input type="radio" name="article" value="0">
<div id="send_to_yes">
       <b>Number</b> <br><input type="text" name="number"><br><br>
</div>
```

Js

```
   $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {  
        if($(this).prop('value') == '1'){
                $("#send_to_yes").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#send_to_yes").hide();
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to `check/uncheck` the radio button and `hide/show` the div based on the database value as well.

```
Yes <input type="radio" name="article" value="1" <?php if($value == 1){ echo 'checked'; } ?>> 

No <input type="radio" name="article" value="0" <?php if($value == 0){ echo 'checked'; } ?>>

<div id="send_to_yes" <?php if($value == 0){ echo 'style="display:none"'; } ?>>
       <b>Number</b> <br><input type="text" name="number"><br><br>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE WITH YES CHECKED BY DEFAULT](http://jsfiddle.net/d5bJV/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding the field with the first line after the document.ready:

```
$("#send_to_yes").hide();
```

So no matter if the YES is set by default the field will be hidden. You would need to fire off the change event, after the page loads, if you want it to automatically display.

You could simplify the hide/show by using the .toggle() function. And you could define the initial load of the field based on the value returned from the DB for the radio buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    <?php
        if($radioValueFromDb == 1) {
           echo <<<JAVASCRIPT
               $("#send_to_yes").show();
JAVASCRIPT;
        } else {
           echo <<<JAVASCRIPT
               $("#send_to_yes").hide();
JAVASCRIPT;
        }
    ?>

    $('.clickIt').bind('click', function(){
        $("#send_to_yes").toggle();
    });

});
```

Changing the HTML a bit:

```
Yes <input type="radio" name="article" class='clickIt' value="1"> 
No <input type="radio" name="article" class='clickIt' value="0">
```