# Is there a function for when a user makes a choice on a radio button to display more fields automatically depending on the choice of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

[When a user makes a choice on a radio button how can I make a function for the form automatically change to display more fields
depending on the choice of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C4A8.png)

Comment: Please share the complete HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: No. No such pre-existing function exists for that. But, you certainly can make one of your own.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please before ask a question look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There most certainly is a function which runs when a user makes a choice on a radio button.

You'll want the "onchange" function.  There are a few examples of how to do this.

Thank you for asking your question.  Unfortunately, it seems that someone has already asked your question.

Here is the previously-asked question:
[JS: Show/hide text field depending on radio button issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758402/js-show-hide-text-field-depending-on-radio-button-issue)
And here is the answer(though it was never accepted):
http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/5ErLu/1/

Best of luck.  I have a question which has been down-voted a lot.  I'm not sure why.  Perhaps my question was a duplicate despite my research.  idk.

btw JQuery makes this easier:

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(...)
```